# control a wpf from matlab by using a c# dll

Tags: c#, wpf, matlab

i would like to know weather it is possible to control some wpf application written in c# by using a c# dll out of matlab.
what i need is the possibility to start the MainWindow and i have to be able 
to get some values into my controller.

What i found so far was things working from c# that use matlab, but the other way round seems not to be that much populatet, as i found nothing i could really use.
I allready tried to import a .net Library, but i dont seem to be able to open a external class from my dll.
So if you could help me on this it would be great.

Regards,
justSomeone

Comment: What is *your dll*? `C#` dll? Then create new window right there, what is the problem?

Comment: My problem was that in a dll file everything has to be static. And putting a bigger application thats more complex into a dll file does not seem to work that easily. For all the references and stuff being quite a lot. After i tried to do the window in the dll, there where xaml parse errors because of missing files which actually are there and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i did just find out, that i can also import my .exe file into Matlab instead of only dlls .
I am using the function **NET.addAssebly('Path.exe')** to do this.
Path.exe is just a symbol that it is directed to the place of the .exe file.

I achieved to be able to use my methods as i wanted i do have my instance of the class. So i am happy now. :D 
But if you have other solutions which are more handy, dont hesitate to post them. There might still be interesting things to discover :)

Regards, 
justSomeone